# Avoid default value in spring <form:input path="var" /> for int variable

Tags: forms, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, spring-3

I'm using Spring 3.1.0 JARs for my application. I have mapped my bean class with view through command name, I have no problem with mapping it works clearly.

The issue is that I'm having an `int` variable in my bean class:

```
private int id;
```

When I map this variable with `<'form:input path="id" />'`, it gives the default value `0` in the text box which I don't want there. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you are referring to a form model with 'id' as the `private` attribute to the model. Have you tried using an `Integer` instead of an `int`. An Integer is the class version of the primitive type `int` and this may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the only way. `int` can't hold an "empty" value, so you need a type which can. `String`, with you converting later, would be the other option.

Comment: @blackpanther Hey thanks blackpanther its nice to get quick and exact answer for what I'm looking for... Thanks a lot its working you have saved my time...

Comment: @blackpanther Due to insufficient reputation I'm not able to vote for your answer... Really sorry...